# Printing the input text with newline if it's too long in Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, ipython

I am giving my program an input to process it. But if the input is too long it still prints it in 1 line. Can I somehow make the program use newline every time it comes to the end of the line?

Comment: Maybe https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html ?

Answer (score 0):

Need more info on what type of input/output we're dealing with
assuming its a string type

```py
def print_with_newlines(text, line_length):
    for i in range(0, len(text), line_length):
        print(text[i:i+line_length])

# Example usage
input_text = "This is a long input text that needs to be printed with newlines when it reaches the end of a line."
line_length = 20
print_with_newlines(input_text, line_length)
```

### OUTPUT

```
This is a long input
 text that needs to
be printed with newl
ines when it reaches
 the end of a line.
```